# problem generating well formatted xml with groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a simple groovy script that generates xml

```
def builder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
def person1 = {
person(id:99){
firstname("John" )
lastname("Smith" )
}
}
def person2 = {
person(id:100){
firstname("Jane" )
lastname("Doe" )
}
}
def personList = {
"person-list" {
out << person1
out << person2
}
}
println builder.bind(personList)
```

However, when this xml is printed...it prints everything in one line. So output is:

```
<person-list><person id='99'>test</person><person id='100'><firstname>Jane</firstname><lastname>Doe</lastname></person></person-list>
```

Is there a way to print this in a well formatted manner like the following?

```
<person-list>
      <person id='99' >
         <firstname>John</firstname>
         <lastname>Smith</lastname>
      </person>
      <person id='100' >
         <firstname>Jane</firstname>
         <lastname>Doe</lastname>
      </person>
</person-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
println XmlUtil.serialize
```

function

Here is [Groovy doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/XmlUtil.html)

Answer (score 0):

See [Best way to pretty print XML response in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231677/best-way-to-pretty-print-xml-response-in-grails) for an all-Groovy answer.