# printing groovy nodechild values

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to print my xml which is coming from an external feed on the console. 
When I do

```
log.debug "${xml}"
```

I get xml values on the console but not the starting and end tags. For example

```
 <fruits>
     <fruit1>apple</fruit1>
     <fruit2>orange</fruit2>
 </fruits>
```

Just prints appleorange
 Just the values concatenated one after other. What is the best value to handle it. I tried this [Best way to pretty print XML response in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231677/best-way-to-pretty-print-xml-response-in-grails) but I get exception at parseText(). I don't know why, because I think the incoming xml is valid.

Update: The type of variable xml is Groovy's NodeChild.

Comment: check xml object's class at first (log.debug(xml.class) output)

Comment: This is the exception errors.GrailsExceptionResolver: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlParser.parseText() is applicable for argument types:

xml is of type NodeChild because this xml I am getting in the request from external webservice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following, if your xml is simple it should satisfy your needs:

`

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
def result = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{
            mkp.yield xml
            }
log.debug result as String
```

`

Comment: It's note a simple xml. The original question is confusing. I will update it. The variable xml is in fact a NodeChild object

Comment: My answer would work then. XmlSlurper.parseText returns a NodeChild object

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
xml.writeTo(writer)
log.debug writer.toString()
```