# How to selectivelly pretty print Grails responses?

Tags: grails, pretty-print

Grails converters can be configured to pretty print (or not) by default.

I like to use the respond method **instead any MarkupBuilder, JsonBuilder** or whatever other library that I should handle **response format**.

```
respond myObject
```

The user can query xml, json or hal.

How can I allow the user to query for a pretty print (assuming default is not)
If the user pass a parameter in the url like this:

```
/foos?pretty=true
```

How can I force the respond to pretty print?

Obs. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231677/best-way-to-pretty-print-xml-response-in-grails) but they all solve the problem statically. I want to change it dinamically on request scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to be able to select the format based on a controller parameter, I think a Grails converter long with `render()` will be better than using `respond()`. Here's an example:

```
import grails.converters.*

class SomeController {
    def foos() {
        def pretty = params.pretty
        def prettyType
        def myObject = /* whatever */

        if(pretty == 'xml') prettyType = XML
        if(pretty == 'json') prettyType = JSON

        if(prettyType) render myObject.asType(prettyType)
        else render myObject        
    }
}
```

The URL would be something like: `/foos?pretty=xml` or `/foos?pretty=json`.

Comment: Thanks emanuel, but this way I'll have to threat every case. Respond means Grails will deal with content negotiation (so far pretty should be true or false and the XML or JSON in the HTTP headers). Response also means user can retrieve HAL, ATOM, HTTP or any other format. And I already declared the converter beans in /grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy. I think it's necessary to handle this using the respond command. Thanks